# How to each an object with objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've have this object:

```
Object {0: Object, 1: Object, 2: Object, 3: Object, 4: Object, 5: Object, 6: Object, 7: Object, 8: Object, 9: Object}
```

I'm trying to do a each so I can print the 10 objects but I'm only printing 1:

```
$(data[0]).each(function(i, item){
    console.log(i);
});
```

The above will print?

```
0
```

This will also print, 0:

```
$(data).each(function(i, item){
    console.log(i);
});
```

How can I print:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 8):

You don't need jquery. Just use JavaScript:

```
for (key in data) {
    console.log(key);
}
```

To get a handle to the inner object, you can use:

```
var innerOb = data[key];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(data,function(key,value){
       console.log(key+""+value);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myobject = [ "apple", "orange", "banana", "melon", "watermelon" ];


$.each( myobject, function( key, value ) {
    console.log(value);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ed5xe/

Answer (score 0):

```
 for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++)
 {
     console.log(data[i]);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var t= {0: Object, 1: Object, 2: Object, 3: Object, 4: Object, 5: Object, 6: Object, 7: Object, 8: Object, 9: Object}

$.each( t, function( key, value ) {
alert( key + ": " + value );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a Vanilla Javascript way of doing it use this:

```
Object.keys(data).forEach(function (d) {
    console.log(d);
}
```

`Object.keys` will just give you an Array of keys of the data object, so 0,1,2 etc.
See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

The `forEach`, then takes the Array of keys, and itterates over each key and the console.log will print them.
See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

This does rely on support of Ecmascript 5 which is the Javascript standard, but most modern browsers support it now.